# how to write regex to get the first level group

Tags: regex

I have a string like this

`env1,env2[data1,data2],env3`

I want a regex to get the first groups

```
env1
env2[data1,data2]
env3
```

then I can write another regex(pcre) to parse data1,data2.

But I don't know how to parse the first level.

@Simon

Yes.
I want grap the env2[data1,data2] firstly.

Comment: What tool/language are you using for this?

Comment: You want to match everything between [ and ]? /.*(\[[^\]]+\]).*/

Comment: `([a-z0-9]+)(\[(.*)\])?` should do the trick but im not super good with regexes so im not posting this as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to capture the env + number + [everything that is not ]...], then you may use this regex:

```
(env\d+\[[^\]]+\])
```

https://regex101.com/r/fE9nF8/1